# Add a column with default constraint of CURRENT_TIMEStAMP() on snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do you know what's the syntax to add a column with a default constraint of CURRENT_TIMEStAMP() on Snowflake?

I was trying:

```
ALTER TABLE clients
ADD COLUMN inserted_at TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ);
```

But it shows me this error:

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid column default expression [CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083448/adding-new-column-in-existing-table-for-default-timestamp-in-snowflake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding new column in existing table for default timestamp in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083448/adding-new-column-in-existing-table-for-default-timestamp-in-snowflake)

Answer (score -1):

As Mike noted, the answers is, "you can not do that", which is the error is say.

What the effect of the command would be, if it "worked for free", would be the same is making a new table, inserting the `CURRENT_TIMESTMAP` for all rows. Which is what happens when you insert a new row, with the value missing. This raises an interesting question, of "what values make sense for the historically inserted rows" and this is in part what the free lunch is missing, because you have to decide what that would mean, because if you had a "years word of data" and `inserted_at` is going to be used to do some neat aggregation, or other "value enriching",  what does it mean have this lump of "one years of values that all have the value now".

Given this is your data, you need to know what what to make of this lump, or how to correctly back-fill that data.

This in general is the nature of "missing" free-lunch features, ether they do not scale to large data for free, which implies as the owner of the data you are in the best position to write DML's the work best for your data, OR the meaning of the data cannot be autogenerated in a way the is "always correct" thus the edge cases of that data, need to be understood by the users.